# Bugzilla emails set to sendmail but still go to mailer.testfile

Tags: sendmail, bugzilla

I have a server with a bugzilla (4.0.9) installation that I did not personally install, but am trying to enable emailing.

I set the email parameter to "test" and verified that the emails do indeed write to

```
/var/lib/bugzilla/data/mailer.testfile
```

When I change the email parameter back to "Sendmail" I find that it continues to write to mailer.testfile instead of sending the email.

Are there any good ways to manually test sending emails with or from bugzilla?  Why would it continue writing to the test file even with the updated params?

**Additional Information:**

The server is running Fedora 16.

sendmail is properly configured and is able to email, tested via:

```
mailx -s "test email" me@domain
```

I have another developer tool on the server as well that can properly send emails, however I am not familiar with how that email service is setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restarting the server resolved this issue.

I also could have simply restarted Bugzilla's jobqueue and it would have worked.

```
/usr/share/bugzilla/jobqueue.pl restart
```

One thing to take away from this is that editing certain params will take effect immediately whereas other params appear to require a reboot.

For example, I modified the mailfrom parameter and was able to see that changing in the mailer.testfile immediately.